# Crm 2011 Setting Title for QueueItem

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a custom entity that is Queue enabled.  I can add it to a Queue using a workflow, however the Queue Item Title remains empty.  No matter what I do I cannot seem to set it or have CRM automagically set it.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to set value on field 'Name' in your custom entity (schema name 'xxx_name', where xxx is prefix that you use for your customization)?